# SQL Server memory benchmarking - how to fill up memory?

Tags: sql-server, memory, benchmark

Recently I was asked by my VMWare colleague how to cause a (non-production and bare install) SQL Server to use up the memory of a machine.

The solution I found in [this forum post](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1565754-3077-1.aspx) does not cause the SQL Server process to use up memory but instead SSMS due to it's output.

As SSMS is only 32 bit, it crashes after about 4 GB, so this is not useful for a  server with 600 GB memory...

Answer (score 2):

The solution I came up with is a slight extension of the forum post I mentioned before (first make sure that your max server memory is set appropriately!):

```
DECLARE @sometable table (id uniqueidentifier)

insert into @sometable
SELECT NEWID()
FROM sys.columns A
CROSS JOIN sys.columns B
CROSS JOIN sys.columns C
```

Indeed you can see that SQL server starts to consume memory when running this query, and of course this does not cause SSMS to fail as there is only the usual "rows affected" output

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to enable Lock Pages in Memory, add TF 834 as a startup parameter, and restart the SQL Server service. This is a [documented trace flag](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/920093/tuning-options-for-sql-server-when-running-in-high-performance-workloa). Quoting from the documentation, with my emphasis in bold:

> Trace flag 834 causes SQL Server to use Microsoft Windows large-page
>   allocations for the memory that is allocated for the buffer pool. The
>   page size varies depending on the hardware platform, but the page size
>   may be from 2 MB to 16 MB. **Large pages are allocated at startup and
>   are kept throughout the lifetime of the process.** Trace flag 834
>   improves performance by increasing the efficiency of the translation
>   look-aside buffer (TLB) in the CPU.
>
> Trace flag 834 applies only to 64-bit versions of SQL Server. You must
>   have the Lock pages in memory user right to turn on trace flag 834.
>   You can turn on trace flag 834 only at startup.
>
> Trace flag 834 may prevent the server from starting if memory is
>   fragmented and if large pages cannot be allocated. Therefore, trace
>   flag 834 is best suited for servers that are dedicated to SQL Server.
>
> Note If you're using the Column Store Index feature from SQL Server
>   2012, we do not recommend enabling trace flag 834.

So if you set Max Server memory to 550 GB, as long as memory isn't fragmented SQL Server will consume 550 GB on the guest VM.

Answer (score 0):

Brent Ozar has the solution you need.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/05/how-to-fake-load-tests-with-sqlquerystress/

It has a couple of options to simulate workloads by calling a stored procedure, that will quickly fill up the memory allocated to SQL.